# Rules :0 :1 :2 :3

Tags: commerce, rules

I'm trying to create a price alert rule and as an action I'm trying to fetch users who flagged a product display. My problem is as follows: When I try to fetch users who flagged a node, I can't distinguish between flags; whereas when I do the same thing for a commerce product, I get tokens like `commerce-product:creator:flag-fiyati-dusunce-haber-ver-flagged:` which requires a number at the end. Reading [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34095/when-using-rules-to-set-a-value-on-a-taxonomy-term-reference-field-i-get-choice), I understand that numbers correspond to variations (am I correct?) but I still have no clue what number to use for any variation (if they indeed correspond to variations). Anyone care to help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number corresponds to the index of a multi valued field, a field that can have more then one value (defined in the content type).

For fields that accept one value, you can use 0. For fields that can contain multiple values, `:n` selects the nth entry for that field.

Since a flag either is enabled or not, I suppose you should be safe with :0. (Omitting this parameter usually has the same effect).

Comment: That's the thing, I can't omit it, it's required; and giving 0 gives me `The variable or parameter node is empty.` :S

Comment: Never encountered such a situation, but that's what the numbers are for... Are you using the data selector? That should give you at least more options on which tokens to use as the list does not show everything.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the data selector.